# python connection with apache Derby Db data base

Tags: python, ubuntu, derby

I'm getting an error while installing DB2; after running command `python setup.py build`, I got the following error in Ubuntu:

```
Your DB2 root is: 
WARNING: it seems that you did not install 'Application Development Kit'.
Compilation may fail.

running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building '_db2' extension
i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Iinclude -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _db2_module.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/_db2_module.o
_db2_module.c:24:21: fatal error: sqlcli1.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sqlcli1.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Please help me to get out of this error.

Comment: Well, *did* you install 'Application Development Kit'?

Comment: i dnt know how to install 'Application Development Kit ' ,please let me know how to install it

Comment: i dnt want use Application Development Kit ...i only want to connect my Derby Db data base with python

Comment: Well you're being told that if you don't install it, *"Compilation may fail"*, then compilation fails, so I guess you don't have a choice. I don't know how to install it, see the installation instructions from whoever provides the module.

Comment: Python won't be able to talk to your Derby database. Derby databases need a JDBC client application to access them. Perhaps you should back up to a higher-level discussion about your architecture and why you are trying to connect a Python program to a Derby database and then people can suggest approaches that may work for you.

Comment: please @BryanPendleton can u tell me how to install JDBC client application to access Derby data base in ubuntu os

Comment: A JDBC client application is a program written in Java. Thus you write Derby client programs in Java. Start here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/getstart/cgsintro.html All you need is the JDK and the Derby libraries.

Comment: can i connect python with derby db in eclips ide?